# How do I grid a three-dimensional region (shell)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to do grid or lattice a shell like below picture?

```
    ‎\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}‎
‎\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}‎
‎\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,patterns,calc}‎
‎\usepackage{xparse}‎
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{5}‎
‎\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{-60}‎
‎\tdplotsetmaincoords{\x}{\y}‎
‎\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]‎
‎\filldraw[ fill=white,looseness=1] (3.6,0,-21)to[bend right] (1.7,3.2,-13)--(1.8,3.5,-12)  to[bend left] (4,0,-22)-‎- ‎cycle;‎
‎\filldraw[ fill=green!20,looseness=1] (4,0,-22)to[bend right] (1.8,3.5,-12)--(1.8,3.5,30)  to[bend left] (4,0,20)-‎- ‎cycle;‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎
‎\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot think of a more automated way to it:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{-60}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\x}{\y}
\newcommand*{\gridstep}{0.15}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\filldraw[fill=white,looseness=1] (3.6,0,-21) coordinate (under surface right) to[bend right] (1.7,3.2,-13) coordinate (under surface left) -- coordinate (middle left) (1.8,3.5,-12) coordinate (bottom left) to[bend left] (4,0,-22) coordinate (bottom right) -- coordinate (middle right) cycle;
\filldraw[fill=green!20,looseness=1] (4,0,-22) to[bend right] (1.8,3.5,-12) -- (1.8,3.5,30) coordinate (top left) to[bend left] (4,0,20) coordinate (top right) -- cycle;

\foreach[count=\ii] \i in {0,\gridstep,...,1}{
        \path (bottom left) to[bend left] coordinate[pos=\i](p\ii) (bottom right);
        \path (under surface left) to[bend left] coordinate[pos=\i](k\ii) (under surface right);
        \draw (p\ii) -- ++(0,0,42);
        \draw (p\ii) -- (k\ii);
        \draw ($(bottom left)!\i!(top left)$) to[bend left] ($(bottom right)!\i!(top right)$);
        };
\draw (middle left) to[bend left] (middle right);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Everything is setup around coordinates specified mid path so if you decide to change the geometry the grid should follow it correctly. I also made a command `\gridstep` which holds the step value (in percentage), changing it will Remake the whole grid except of the line from bottom surface to top, that one is drew seperately.

[image: Compilation result]